# How does $(2, 1 + \sqrt{-5})$ become principal in the Hilbert class field?

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic, class-field-theory

Let $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$ and $L = K(\sqrt{-1})$ its Hilbert class field. Then according to the [principal ideal theorem](https://kskedlaya.org/cft/sec_artinrec.html), the non-principal ideal $(2, 1+\sqrt{-5})$ becomes principal in $\mathcal{O}_L$. In the link above, it is suggested that $(2, 1 + \sqrt{-5})\mathcal{O}_L = (1 + \sqrt{-1})\mathcal{O}_L$. I can see it is reasonable, as both sides square to the ideal $(2)\mathcal{O}_L$. However, I am unable to see why $1 + \sqrt{-5}\in (1 + \sqrt{-1}) \mathcal{O}_L$.

Comment: $(1+i\sqrt5)/(1+i)=(1+i\sqrt5-i+\sqrt5)/2=((1+\sqrt5)/2)+(i(\sqrt5-1)/2)$ is an integer in $K$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson yeah you are right! thanks!